# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build.gradle

[image]

**  android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined**

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: The question would be better posed in plain English, without the class paths etc. The image alone does not help; there should be some more context/code about what you're trying to accomplish.